# How can I disable W3 Total Cache Image Lazy Load for Specific Post Type?

Tags: plugins, hooks, plugin-w3-total-cache

I'm using W3 Total Cache plugin for my WordPress site.
I've enabled Lazy Load setting option, but I want to disable the option for the specific post type. How can I hook and disable it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the W3 Total Cache plugin author's [website](https://www.boldgrid.com/support/w3-total-cache/configuring-lazy-loading-for-your-wordpress-website-with-w3-total-cache/#fine-tuning-your-lazy-loading-configuration-in-w3-total-cache), you can prevent individual images from lazy loading if you add the image URLs to the "Exclude words" section of the User Experience > Lazy Loading section.

This is helpful when using page builders that do not give you direct access to the class attribute of the image tag (such as Elementor).

Comment: I was able to disable lazy load for images using class "skip-lazy", it didn't work for class "no-lazy"

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be a bit too late but here goes: W3 Total Cache will skip lazy loading images that have class "no-lazy". This means that you can hook to the [get_the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) filter [post_thumbnail_html](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/) and add the class to the image.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Disable W3 Total Cache lazy load for post type "post"
 *
 * @param string $html
 * @param int $post_id
 * @param int $image_id
 * @param string|int[] $size
 * @param string|array $attr
 */
function _post_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_id, $image_id, $size, $attr ){

    if( !empty( $html ) ){
        $post = get_post( $post_id );

        if( 'post' === $post->post_type ){
            if( isset( $attr['class'] ) ){
                $attr['class'] .= ' no-lazy';
            }else{
                if( !is_array( $attr ) ){
                    $attr = array();
                }

                $attr['class'] = 'no-lazy';
            }

            $html = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $size, false, $attr );
        }

    }

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', '_post_thumbnail_html', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.boldgrid.com/support/w3-total-cache/configuring-lazy-loading-for-your-wordpress-website-with-w3-total-cache/) the class to use is now "skip-lazy".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter,

```
function ar_lazyload_deactivate() {
    if ( is_singular( 'posttype name' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'do_rocket_lazyload', '__return_false' );
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp', __NAMESPACE__ . '\ar_lazyload_deactivate' );
```

Comment: It's wp rocket. It talking about w3 total cache. Is it using the same hook?